# With which programming language, Ports can be handled effectively, through which Spywares / keyloggers communicate

Tags: sockets, networking, port

I Browsed many "Learn Networking" Questions here, but it is different.

I am Running on windows, wants to **learn a PL for networking**. Aim is to **handle Ports effectively** for the **purpose of blocking Spywares, keyloggers communication.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block ports you have no option but to write in a language that can be used to write drivers that can be inserted into the TCP/IP network stack ... unless possibly the Windows Firewall allows for pluggable modules, in which case you are still stuck with whatever is supported for that.

Comment: thanks. Which Programming language is used to write windows drivers?

Comment: @user1495089 C, maybe C++ if you're lucky.